# str_replace wordpress menu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I have a menu of the following hyperlinks.

```
1) Our Work
2) Clients
3) About Us
4) Contact
```

My question is, how can i prevent the following code to not replace the `li` in 'Clients'?

It outputs 'Caents', although I do need it stop outputting the `<li>` tags in the menu.

```
<nav>
<?php 

// first let's get our nav menu using the regular wp_nav_menu() function with special parameters
$cleanmenu = wp_nav_menu( array( 
'container' => false, // this is usually a div outside the menu ul, we don't need it
'depth'       => 0,
'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title',
'echo' => false, // don't display it just yet
) );

// Find the closing bracket of each li and the opening of the link, then all instances of "li"
$find = array('><a','li');
// Replace the former with nothing (a.k.a. delete) and the latter with "a"
$replace = array('','a');
echo str_replace( $find, $replace, $cleanmenu );

?>
</nav>
```

Comment: Even if you were to succeed with this you'll end up with and extra closing `</a>` and a bunch of anchors mysteriously wrapped in `<ul>` tags.  Not sure what you're trying to do here but it seems like there's probably a better approach.  What's the goal in removing the `<li>` tags?

Comment: Ultimately I am trying to show my Wordpress menu without the <ul> and <li> tags. It should just show <nav> and then each '<a href="">menu item</a>'.

This is what I have at the moment. It works but doesn't show the current_menu_item?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend parsing html that way.  Take some time and learn the PHP DOM extension.  It's quite flexible.  Here's an example that does what you want and illustrates some basic methods for parsing html with php:

```
    <nav>
    <?php 

    $cleanmenu = wp_nav_menu( array( 
        'container' => false,
        'depth'       => 0,
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title',
        'echo' => false,
    ) );

    $html = '';     

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->loadHTML($cleanmenu);
    $listItems = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');
    foreach($listItems as $li) {
        $id = $li->getAttribute('id');
        $class = $li->getAttribute('class');
        $href = $li->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
        $text = $li->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $html .= '<a id="' . $id . '" class="' . $class . '" href="' . $href . '">' . $text . '</a>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo $html;

    ?>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hacking the output with string replacements you should use the tools WordPress gives you to create the desired output.

To get rid of the `<li>` tags you can create a custom menu walker. This walker is basically directly from [this example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker#General_Menu_Example), I just removed the comments and the `<li>` from the output:

```
class Walker_Custom_Menu extends Walker {
    var $db_fields = array(
        'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 
        'id'     => 'db_id' 
    );
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $output .= sprintf( "\n<a href='%s'%s>%s</a>",
            $item->url,
            ( $item->object_id === get_the_ID() ) ? ' class="current"' : '',
            $item->title
        );
    }

}
```

Now you can use this walker in your `wp_nav_menu()` call:

```
$cleanmenu = wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'container' => false,
    'depth'       => 0,
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title',
    'echo' => false,
    'before' => '',
    'after' => '',
    // use <nav> instead of <ul> to enclose the menu.
    'items_wrap' => '<nav>%3$s</nav>',
    // use the cusom walker here
    'walker' => new Walker_Custom_Menu()
) );
```

Generated output:

```
<nav>
<a href='http://test'>Our Work</a>
<a href='http://Test'>Clients</a>
<a href='http://test'>About Us</a>
<a href='http://test'>Contact</a></nav>
```

Comment: Will this also output the current_menu_item?

Comment: Not sure without testing it further, the walker only contains a line to add the class "current" to the current item. You can easily modify it to output all you need.